# Vue subrouting with navbar and sidebar

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to set up a routing system with vue. For my purpose, I need a fixed navbar on the top that needs to be displayed on every page and a sidebar that I want to display only on the settings page. Following the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html) I tried:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/settings',
    name: 'Settings',
    component: Settings,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'route1',
        name: 'Route1',
        component: Route1
      },
      {
        path: 'route2',
        name: 'Route2',
        component: Route2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then on the settings template:

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex items-start">
    <div class="lg:w-3/12 w-12 sm:w-16 md:w-24 pb-10 lg:pr-8">
      <Sidebar />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lg:w-9/12 w-full pt-10 pb-8 text-justify">
  // My subroute goes here  
  </div>
</template>
```

I feel that I'm missing something. First, I can't understand how to properly display the subroutes. I tried with `<router-view />` but it seems to refer to the parent navigation.
Second, I don't want the user to visit the `/settings` route but only `/settings/route1` and `settings/route2`.

I can achieve this by simply adding the sidebar in every settings route but this seems bad because it forces the `<Sidebar/>` component to be mounted every time

Where am I wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Hi, as you are using the nested routes, then it will always refer to the parent navigation, and to display the nested route you need to use `<router-view></router-view>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably have guessed, the `<router-view />` element goes in your `Settings` component:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex items-start">
    <div class="lg:w-3/12 w-12 sm:w-16 md:w-24 pb-10 lg:pr-8">
      <Sidebar />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lg:w-9/12 w-full pt-10 pb-8 text-justify">
    <router-view /> <!-- Here is your router view --> 
  </div>
</template>
```

Then as it was pointed out in the comments, `/settings` will always be a valid route.
What you can do when the client directly navigates to `/settings` is to replace the current route with one of the two children (possibly based on some logic) in the `mounted` hook:

```
  mounted() {
    if(this.$router.currentRoute.path.endsWith('/settings')) {
      this.$router.replace('/settings/route1')
    }
  }
```

Or use `$router.push()` instead based on what you want the navigation history to look like.